# How should I call someone in street?

Tags: word-usage

Let say some thing have fall from the someone who walk in front of you in street ! Can I call him/her `anata` or `sumimasen` to notice ? In my country we usually say `brother` to boy and `sister` to girl .

Comment: Related (or duplicate?): https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/59354/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/56507/9831

Comment: In such a situation, when I was living in Japan, I used to say `moshi moshi!` to call the person's attention, then add something like `otoshimono desu (yo!)`...

Answer (score 2):

You should always use a non-specific attention-getter such as 'sumimasen' first. That should be sufficient. If not, say it louder. If that fails, run up to them and tap them gently on the shoulder.

What you would call the person who dropped the object depends on who the person is - namely: their age in general, their age relative to you, their gender, and their social position relative to yours. To put it more simply, there are many different terms of address, depending strictly on who is being addressed.

While you can call someone brother, sister, aunt, wife, husband, grandmother, grandfather, etc., until you know those forms properly and when they apply it is much better to leave them alone.

Calling someone by the wrong address can create more of an uncomfortable situation than is necessary to get their attention.